# Domain Validated SSL google oauth2

Tags: ssl, oauth-2.0

I'm currently in the process of implementing google's oauth2 signin and now I need to validate the user signin before I allow access.

Will a domain-validated SSL certificate tied to my server be sufficient to request tokeninfo from Google's oauth2 login-service?

(Specifically https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XXXX)

Or do I need it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up purchasing a domain validated SSL and it was apparently sufficient to request tokeninfo from Google's oauth2.